# Finding out time before a set period of tme before a meeting

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to create a reminder service which I am using in windows task scheduler. However what I need is to replicate the ability of outlook the way it does  Beside the snoze button. But it says cannot convert date time to a bool at the comparsion.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the appointments based on a reminder of time
/// </summary>
/// <param name="reminderLength">Length of the reminder.</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public List<Appointment> GetAppointments(int reminderLength)
{
    List<Appointment> list = new List<Appointment>();

    try
    {
        var q = from a in apertureNetEntities.Appointments.Where(a => a.Start.Value.AddMinutes(-reminderLength))
                select a;

        list = q.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)

    {
        string inner = string.Empty;
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            inner = ex.InnerException.ToString();
        }
        logger.Error("Error in List<Appointment> function GetAppointments " + ex.ToString() + " " + inner);
        return null;
    }

    return list;
}
```

**Edit**

The error accounts here

> Start.Value.AddMinutes(-reminderLength)

Comment: Where does the error occur?

Comment: @Remuze i edit above my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following line:

```
apertureNetEntities.Appointments.Where(a => a.Start.Value.AddMinutes(-reminderLength))
```

`AddMinutes` returns a `DateTime`. `Where` expects a function that evaluates to a boolean inside it. You need to compare your DateTime to something in order to avoid the error.

e.g.:

```
apertureNetEntities.Appointments.Where(a => a.Start.Value.AddMinutes(-reminderLength) < DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: what would u recomend as I am trying to just find out the time 30 mins etc before metting starts

Comment: But if i am wanting to only find out 30 mins bofore start column then that does not really work.

Comment: I've swapped the operator around. It will now return everything that starts in 30 minutes or less (assuming that is the value of reminderLength). You may want to add another condition to avoid past appointments etc. but the pattern should be clear.

Comment: I have a status column I use for that natur so i do

Answer (score 1):

@strickt01 is correct.

personally i prefer formatting it something like; its easier to read.

```
//where the start time is greater than now minus 30min
var reminderLength = 30;
var timeAfter = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-reminderLength);
apertureNetEntities.Appointments.Where(a => a.Start > timeAfter)
```

**Update** maybe something like....**??**

//looking for all appointment starting in the next 30min from now.

//but only in the next 30 min

```
var reminderLength = 30;
var timeBefore = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(reminderLength);
var currentDateTime = Datetime.Now;
A.Appointments
   .Where(x => x.Start > currentDateTime //greater than now 
            && x.Start < timeBefore //less now + 30min
          )
```

Comment: Yes, it seems sometimes that people have an obsession with making everything a 'one-liner'. This makes it very clear what is happening.

Comment: The problem with this code is that it returns ALL appointments starting after 30 minutes ago. So appointments in the far distant future will be returned. The requirement is to return only those appointments starting in the next 30 minutes.

Comment: So including not greater than now will fix it? if so i will add to answer